# Python abstract method inside implemented base class method

Tags: python, abstract, abc

I'm able to authenticate against some RESTful API with one of the following methods:

- password
- certificate
- anonymous

I've created **AuthenticationBase** class and its subclassess:

- PasswordAuthentication
- CertificateAuthentication
- AnonymousAuthentication

Basically authentication take two steps:

1. get_rsts_token
2. set_access_token - You need RSTS token first

**set_access_token** has the same implementation across subclasses but **get_rsts_token** differs so I've tried something like this:

```
import abc

ABC = abc.ABCMeta('ABC', (object,), {'__slots__': ()})

class AuthenticationBase(ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_rsts_token(self):
        pass

    def set_access_token()
       rsts_token = self.get_rsts_token()
       access_token = retrieve_token(rsts_token)
```

but it leads to an error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AuthenticationBase with abstract methods get_rsts_token
```

I wish to avoid rewriting **set_access_token** in all subclasses. How to achieve this?

Comment: This code doesn't produce the error you're talking about. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You don't have to; you just have to provide a definition of `get_rsts_token`, because that error gets raised before you ever try to run `set_access_token`.

Comment: @ForceBru: I've checked once again and You're right. But how to enforce in set_access_token() method that I want to invoke get_rsts_token() from subclass and not self.get_rsts_token()